# random list from a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need the `randomList` function parameters to be:

- the number of elements it should have
- a low number
- high number to create the list with.

Im not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

```
from random import randrange
import random

def randomList(x,y,z):
    myList = []
    for x in range(x, y, z):
        myList.append(random.randrange(x, y, z))
    print(myList)

randomList(1, 5, 1)
```

Comment: In your example low number is 5 and high number is 1, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's not clear what your intended results are, but you repeat ```x``` here which is at least confusing, if not the actual problem: ```for x in range(x, y, z)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question I assumed that `x` would be the amount of numbers added to `myList` and that `y` and `z` would be the minimum and maximums. Using that information I got this code: it iterates `x` amount of times and each time appends(adds) an integer from `(1, 5)`.

```py
from random import randrange
import random

def randomList(x,y,z):
    myList = []
    for i in range(x):
        myList.append(random.randrange(y, z))
    print(myList)

randomList(5, 1, 6)
```

This would give 5 random numbers, that have a minimum value of 1 (`y`) and a maximum of 5(`z`)(z is exclusive).

The output would look something like the following:

```py
[1, 5, 2, 5, 2]
```